# collapse article when next article is expanded (Readmore.js - Extension)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [Readmore.js](https://github.com/jedfoster/Readmore.js) plugin. I looked up various solutions for my following issue but none of them seemed to be perfect.

I want to add a function which collapses the previously expanded article - if any, when readmore is pressed.

Thank's to Josh, I manage to flag a variable `isOpen` as `true` or `false` when an article is expanded/collapsed. Now I'm trying to figure out how to collapse the an article when a new one is expanded.

```
<script>
$('#info').readmore({

moreLink: '<a href="#">More examples and options</a>',
maxHeight: 390,
afterToggle: function(trigger, element, expanded) {
if(! expanded) { // The "Close" link was clicked
$('html, body').animate( { scrollTop: element.offset().top }, {duration: 100 } );
}
}
});

$('article').readmore({maxHeight: 240});


var isOpen = true;
$('article').readmore({
afterToggle: function(trigger, element, expanded) {

if (expanded) {
  isOpen = true;
}
if(! expanded) { 
  isOpen = false;    }
  }
});

$('article').readmore({
beforeToggle: function(trigger, element, expanded) {

if (isOpen) {

}
  }
}); 
    </script>
```

Thanks already...

Comment: As a tip, don't try and work out which one is open - collapse them all and open the one you want! Collapsing them all won't do anything detrimental, as nothing will actually happen to the ones already collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

As Readmore.js [adds a class to expanded blocks](https://github.com/jedfoster/Readmore.js#the-options) you can identify and close them by something like this:

```
$('article').readmore({
    beforeToggle: function(trigger, element, expanded) {
        $( '.readmore-js-expanded' ).readmore( 'close' );
    }
} );
```

---

Edit: seeing that Readmore.js does not seem to provide a 'close' method you may need to fake that by triggering the close event over the anchor:

```
$('article').readmore({
    lessLink:     '<a class="readmore-lesslink">Show less</a>',
    beforeToggle: function(trigger, element, expanded) {
        $( '.readmore-js-expanded' )
            .find( 'a.readmore-lesslink' )
                .trigger( 'click' );
    }
} );
```

I did not test this at all but it should get you started I guess.

Comment: It does not work. I'm a bit uncertain how to identify the issue. I placed the code, as I imagined, inside the index.html using `<script></script>`.

Initially I thought of using something like: `document.getElementByClass(".readmore-js-toggle").addEventListener("click", function(){...});`, but also unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It is working for me:

```
$('article').readmore({
        collapsedHeight: 80px;
        lessLink: '<a class="readmore-lesslink">Show less</a>',
            beforeToggle: function(trigger,element,more) {
            $(element).siblings("a.readmore-lesslink").not($(element).next()).trigger( "click" );
          }
    });
```